# how to use BigQueryIO.read using SerializableFunction() instead of BigQueryIO.readTableRows()

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

How to use `BigQueryIO.read` using `SerializableFunction()` instead of `BigQueryIO.readTableRows()`? As I've heard that `readTableRows` is time consuming.

Our objective is to build dataflow to execute bigquery select query and write results to bigquery and GCS.To achieve that, I have used `BigQueryIO.readTableRows()` to read data, but I've heard it is slow so what to use 
     `BigQueryIO.read` using `SerializableFunction()` to retrieve complete row. Could you please help me?

```java
// to read data from bigquery  
p.apply(
  BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
    .fromQuery("myquery")
    .usingStandardSql()
    .withoutValidation()
    .withQueryLocation("EU")
  )

// to write result set to bigquery 
  .apply(
    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
      .to(tableSpec)
      .withJsonSchema(tableSchemaJson)
      .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
  );
```

How to achieve same thing using `BigQueryIO.read` using `SerializableFunction()`?

Comment: Have you found `readTableRows` to be slow? Where have you heard that it's slow? I think it must be acceptable - but do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: apache beam java tutorial documents says below statement:     
readTableRows returns a PCollection of BigQuery TableRow objects. Each element in the PCollection represents a single row in the table. Integer values in the TableRow objects are encoded as strings to match BigQuery’s exported JSON format. This method is convenient, but can be 2-3 times slower in performance compared to read(SerializableFunction).